# setsockopt returning SOCKET_ERROR on MAC

Tags: macos, qt, sockets, winsock

Following is the information about my dev environment : 
**Windows:**
OS: Windows 10
Qt: 5.15.2
Compiler: MSVC2019

**MAC:**
OS: macOS Catalina (v 10.15.7)
Qt: 5.15.2
Compiler: clang 64 bit

In my application, I am sending some multicast packets to other instances of the same application running on different PCs. Following is the code snippet:

```
        QUdpSocket myMulticastSocket;
        // PC_PORT_TO_RECEIVE is the port number used for all application client multicast communication
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
        myMulticastSocket.bind(PC_PORT_TO_RECEIVE, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
#else
        myMulticastSocket.bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, PC_PORT_TO_RECEIVE, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
#endif
        QHostAddress tHostAddr = lstValidIface.at(i);  // lstValidIface is a list of valid network interfaces available.

        // don't take any action for local host
        if ((tHostAddr == QHostAddress::LocalHost) ||
            (tHostAddr == QHostAddress::LocalHostIPv6) ||
            (tHostAddr == QHostAddress::AnyIPv6) ||
            (tHostAddr == QHostAddress::Any))
            continue;

        DWORD tIPAddr = htonl(tHostAddr.toIPv4Address());
        int sktDesptr = myMulticastSocket.socketDescriptor();

        int iErrCode = setsockopt(sktDesptr, 
                                IPPROTO_IP, 
                                IP_MULTICAST_IF, 
                                (char*)&tIPAddr, 
                                sizeof(tIPAddr));
```

The above code is working fine in Windows environment. But in MAC, call to setsockopt is returning SOCKET_ERROR (-1). I am not able to figureout, where it is going wrong.

Please let me know if anything wrong in the above code ir anything needs to be done additional to make this code work on MAC.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at using [`QUdpSocket::joinMulticastGroup(..)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#joinMulticastGroup) rather than `setsockopt`?

Comment: What you actually should be looking for are the `::joinMulticastGroup` and `::setMulticastInterface` member functions of `QUdpSocket`. These provide portable access to what you want without messing around with subtile differences between OSs. Also, the contents of `errno` after the `setsockopt` call is crucial.

Comment: Replacing the bind method call for the socket for Mac with the one for Windows mentioned above, helped me solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the bind method call for the socket for Mac with the one for Windows mentioned above, helped me solving the issue.